# How to filter json data by user_id login ionic 3?

Tags: php, json, angular, ionic3

I am a beginner at Ionic 3, please help.
I succes to display data from API json in PHP
but how to display json data via the id_user login in localstorage?
currently only displays all data including other id_user.
Thank you

This is my .ts

```
export class PembayaranPage {
  data : Observable<any>;
  userdata: any = [];
  public item : Array<any> = [];

  private url = "http://localhost/apiioniclogin2/"

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public http : HttpClient,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public alertCtrl : AlertController) { 
      this.userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userlogin')) || [];
    console.log(this.userdata);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PembayaranPage');
  }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.load();
  }
  load() {
    this.http
    .get(this.url+'test.php')
    .subscribe((data : any) => {
      console.dir(data);
      this.item = data;
    },(error : any) => {
      console.dir(error);
    });
  }
```

this is my json

```
    {
    "invoiceid": "3",
    "studentid": "1",
    "title": "title test",
    "description": "Test sample",
    "amount": "35000",
    "amount_paid": "0",
    "due": "35000",
    "creation_timestamp": "1543683600",
    "status": "unpaid"
},
{
    "invoiceid": "4",
    "studentid": "2",
    "title": "titletest2",
    "description": "descriptionnn",
    "amount": "10000",
    "amount_paid": "10000",
    "due": "0",
    "creation_timestamp": "1543683600",
    "status": "paid"
},
```

this is my .html

```
 Id_user Login: {{userdata[0].parent_id}}
<ion-item *ngFor="let itemData of item ">
  <ion-row >
    <ion-col>
      <div>
        <span>Id_user: {{itemData.studentid}}</span><br>
        <span>{{itemData.title}}</span><br>
        <span>{{itemData.amount}}</span><br>
        <span>{{itemData.description}}</span><br>
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

Please Help Me.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question makes me pretty confused. If you want to show user_id specific data in the list you can use a filter like you can create a custom pipe using below link :
https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/creating-custom-filter-pipe-angular-2/

or you can add a condition in your loop to check for the data using *ngIf

```html
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let itemData of item" >
    <ion-item  *ngIf="itemData.studentid == stored_id">
      <ion-row >
        <ion-col>
          <div>
            <span>Id_user: {{itemData.studentid}}</span><br>
            <span>{{itemData.title}}</span><br>
            <span>{{itemData.amount}}</span><br>
            <span>{{itemData.description}}</span><br>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

where stored_id is the actual userid which is stored after user login. In component.ts file define stored_id as user id.

Comment: Im sorry make your confused :) i can't speak english properly...
Great, I almost finished, but how define stored_id as user id?
thank alot sir

Comment: you are getting user id in userdata[0].parent_id when the user login into the app. As you mentioned above you are storing user data in local storage. So, now you can replace stored_id with userdata[0].parent_id.